# Volume between plane and paraboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I need to find the centroid of the following body but first I need to find the volume which I'm currently stuck with but I think I'm close

$z=2y$, $z=x^2+y^2$

The integral I found is

$$\int _0^4\:\int _0^{2\pi }\:\int _0^{\sqrt{z-1}}\:rdrd\theta \:dz$$

I think I did something wrong for the bounds of r

I also tried it using cartesian coordinates which gave me

$$\int _0^4\:\int _0^{\frac{z}{2}}\:\int _{-\sqrt{z-y^2}}^{\sqrt{z-y^2}}\:dxdydz$$

this also gave me the wrong answer

The volume should be $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z = 2y$ and $z = x^2 + y^2$ should give you $x^2+y^2 = 2y \implies x^{2} + \left(y - 1\right)^{2} = 1$. This is the constraint. Looks like a circle centered at $\left(0,1\right)$. Cylindrical coordinated about that point?
$(x,y,z) \mapsto (r\cos(\theta),1 + r\sin\theta,z)$, where $0\leq r \leq 1$, $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, and $r^{2} + 2 r \sin{\left(\theta \right)} + 1\leq z \leq  2r\sin\theta + 2$. So we set up the integral:
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{r^{2} + 2 r \sin{\left(\theta \right)} + 1}^{2r\sin\theta + 2} r\, dz\, d\theta \, dr \\= \int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{2 \pi}\int\limits_{r^{2}}^{1} r\, dz\, d\theta\, dr = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: How did you get the first equation $x^2+y^2=y$, why should it not be $x^2+y^2=2y$?

Comment: Yeah my bad fixed it

Comment: Thank you, this helped :)

Comment: (Extra question if you are willing to answer), for the mass of inertia I should calculate the integral $\frac{2m}{\pi }\int _0^1\:\int _0^{2pi}\:\int _{r²}^1\:r^2dzd\theta \:dr$ but this doesn't give me the right answer which should be $\frac{4m}{3}$

Comment: I think you mean moment of inertia, in which case I'm also gonna assume you mean the moment about the origin. In that case you have to multiply the integrand by $x^2+y^2=r^{2} + 2 r \sin{\left(\theta \right)} + 1$. So the formula is:
$$\frac{2m}{\pi} \int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{2 \pi}\int\limits_{r^{2}}^{1} r \left(r^{2} + 2 r \sin{\left(\theta \right)} + 1\right)\, dz\, d\theta\, dr = \frac{4 m}{3}$$

Comment: Yes! That is what I meant, forgot to mention I was looking for $I_x$, thank you once again! :)